# Want Stacked column highchart to represent data in two column

Tags: graph, highcharts

I had posted one question but no body put there suggestion on that , Title of that question is Want Stacked column highchart to represent data in two column. Please help to answer.

Comment: what you are expecting from us ?

Comment: I want a bit guidance and help on that question if possible.

Comment: Have you checked this link http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked

Comment: it does not fill the requirement. i want chart http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic in this http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked format showing stats of two categories.

Comment: You question should be more specific, you have to give enough info about what really you are trying to do, then you could have get the answer what you are expecting. Hope you understood how a question has to be posted here. Edit your question make more specific. Somebody will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are expecting Stacked and Grouped Column chart. Check this

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped

Comment: Thanks Shafeeq for your help. An d from next time i will try to be more specific on what i want to discuss.